# Circular linear regression to estimate missing values in circular data

Tags: regression, circular-statistics

I have a data set of wind direction and wind speed data but some of the wind direction data are missing. There are many good candidates for predictors of wind direction. I want to use the R package circular (see example below) but I cannot figure out how to convert the estimated regression coefficients and predictor variable (x) to get estimates of y. The back transformation described in the documentation is `fitted = mu + 2*atan(beta'*x)` but that does not produce plausible estimates. What am I missing?

## Fit a circular-linear regression model.

````
library(circular)

set.seed(1234)
x <- cbind(rnorm(10), rep(1, 10))
y <- circular(2*atan(c(x%*%c(5,1)))) + rvonmises(10, mu=circular(0), kappa=100)
lm.circular(y=y, x=x, init=c(5,1), type='c-l', verbose=TRUE)
```
````

Comment: The formula  `fitted = mu + 2*atan(beta'*x)` is the original transformation: it's certainly not a back-transformation.